# Python web/server authentication

Tags: python, authentication, webserver, python-requests

I am trying to create a very basic app that will be able to connect to a web server which host my college assignments, results, and more and notify me when ever there's something new on it. Currently I am trying to get the hang of the requests module, but I am not able to login as the server uses [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihlyS.png) kind of authentication, and it gives me error 401 unauthorized.

I tried searching how to authenticate to web servers tried using sockets, with no luck. Could you please help me find out how to do this?

EDIT: I am using python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the headers in the response for that URL, I think the server is trying to use [NTLM authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789031(v=vs.110).aspx).

Try installing [`requests-ntlm`](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm) (e.g. with `pip install requests_ntlm`) and then doing this:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

requests.get('http://moodle.mcast.edu.mt:8085/',
    auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username', 'password'))
```

Comment: still prompts the login form. Does not login.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this should work. Does your user name or password contain any characters that might need to be specially-encoded (for now we can look for anything that's not a letter and not a number).

Comment: i retried couple of minutes ago this time i used chrome and it authenticated me succefully. so how do i got about doing that in python? connect using requests and providing the host name with  this http://<user>:<pass>@moodle.mcast.edu.mt:8085 signature?

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko, I did a bit more digging. It looks like this site actually uses NTLM authentication. I have updated my answer with this in mind.

Comment: yea i was wondering what was the NTML in Authorization request. I am trying to install the module. I think this should be it tho

Comment: damn it, i've tried everything i am still getting a 401 err even with this method which should be correct

Comment: oh man i did a silly mistake, i didnt replace the domain part with actual domain name

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a simple authentication header within the socket request headers.

Example;

```
import base64

mySocket.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic %s\r\n\r\n' % base64.b64encode('user:pass'))
```

Python 3x;

```
import base64

template = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic %s\r\n\r\n'
mySocket.send(bytes(template % base64.b64encode(bytes('user:pass', 'UTF-8')), 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: i tried but i still get this error TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface. i also had changed the last part to base64.b64encode(bytes('u:p', encoding='utf-8')) still get that error

Comment: Edited the initial solution and added the python 3x way, I've just tested it on my workspace and it worked fine with no type errors.

Comment: yea im still on it. trying to understand what BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe means

Comment: Error 32 (BrokenPipeError) gets thrown when the other side fully closed connection and you get a SIGPIPE message. (usually you ignore it w/ try-except)

Comment: nvm that, i had forgot to connect to the server. dealing with other stuff here at the same time. but uh i got this err b'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\nServer: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\n'

Comment: Diagnosed quickly the passed arguments again, try to pass 'authorization:Basic %s' to the server instead of the capital version 'Authorization: Basic %s'. It should work, but I'll setup a raw connection to further test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105308/discussion-between-l33t-and-evgeny-danilenko).

Answer (score 0):

They might not supply a programmatic API with which to authorize requests. If that is the case, you could try using selenium to manually open a browser and fill the details in for you. Selenium has handling for alert boxes too apparently, though I haven't used it myself.

Comment: I looked at the link you posted, and I don't think that, that would work, as it is "searching the element by id" and pressing f12 to see website info does not share any elements besides that frame.

Comment: Yeah you're right; I hadn't realised it was a pop-up box type thing (I thought it was an html form from the screenshot)